# Is there a way to find the 'the last factory reset time'?

Tags: factory-reset

Is there a way to find the 'the last factory reset time' ? any logs or any other stuff like that? Please reply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems there is a way to find out about the last factory reset -- provided it was followed by a Google account initialization:

- Go to the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard), login with your Google account.
- Scroll to the section labeled "Android" and expand it (by clicking its title / the LGM [little green man])
- Check for the device in question

Associated, you will find a date of registry. That doesn't reflect the first time a device was added, but the last time the Google account was activated on the device. So if you activate your Google account following a factory-reset, this field is updated and thus reflects this point-in-time.

Comment: @Firelord As I was not especially interested, I didn't check any further. But I'm pretty sure there's some way via ADB – with root, e.g. find the earliest creation-time of a directory below `/data/data`: pick any system app should suffice, as their app-directories would be created at the first boot following a factory-reset.